# SMO restore and Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, smo, database-restore

I have an application that uses SMO to manage databases. It works great on XP and Server 2003.
However, when I try to run it on Windows 7, I get the following exception:

*Restore failed for Server 'localhost'.  ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser, Version=9.0.242.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser, Version=9.0.242.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'*

Is this a UAC/permissions issue? Windows 7 is the only variable between the two computers.
Database used is Sql Server 2005 on both machines as well. Using .NET 3.5.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue had to do with the fact this dll is not installed on x64 Windows. To resolve it, I had to download SQL Server feature pack:
[SQL Server Feature Pack.](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6C3E9EF-BA29-4A43-8D69-A2BED18FE73C&displaylang=en)